# My GitHub profile is not visible in public and I can't add collaborators to my public repository

Tags: github

I have created a new GitHub profile and Enabled 2Factor Auth and SSH access to my GitHub account as well. But when I tried to search my profile on GitHub It shows a 404 page and When I try to add collaborators to my public repository, it gives the error message "User Can't be added."

My account is from Sri Lanka, so It doesn't have any region-based restrictions and My account is not set to private under Settings -> Contributions & activity -> Make profile private and hide activity.

Public profile: https://github.com/aldtanpc

Page Returned 404 page on GitHub and Can't add collaborators on to a public GitHub repository.

Comment: Do you have multiple Github accounts ?

Comment: Hello yusuf, yes, This GitHub profile is created from a new email address that was provided by the company, which is a Gmail mail. I also have a personal GitHub account as well, but It's not logged in from the same browser.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check the username again?

I used my account and it works fine: https://api.github.com/users/unchaineddev

whereas for your [account](https://api.github.com/users/aldtanpc) it says:

```bash
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/users/users#get-a-user"
}
```

Check this [doc](https://docs.github.com/rest/users/users#get-a-user)